# create a php proxy page

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm looking for a way to load a full-functional copy of a web site inside a php proxy page in order to be able to grab and change part of its elements and styles.

*I decided to post this question to merge my previous two into a more relevant evolution:

[live change any site visualization properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949067/live-change-any-site-visualization-properties)

[load external site and change its visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778825/load-external-site-and-change-its-visualization)*

I have found `cURL` functions useful to load the page (eg. `www.google.it`; for `google.com` I received a `302 redirection`, but I won't face it now).
Some of the page elements, like the image logo, are not properly loaded; this should be due to the original relative path to the site resources. I have to manually add "`//google.it`" before them to fix, and it worked.

Now I have another issue: 
How is it possible to go further in the site navigation? 
When I click any link the page is reloaded with its "real" destination. I suppose I have to reload my php and use the href link attribute as url to load (I can do that).
But what about the submit buttons? How can I redirect their destination?

Answer (score 0):

Use [an existing proxy](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20proxy%20github) for that.

Generally you'll have to just find all the strings matching the old domain name and change them into your url, so every link on the page will turn from being `www.bla.com/page.htm` into `proxy.com/page.htm`.

This will also require some server setup thanks to possible ajax requests and relative paths. Besides, super hard would be to catch dynamically constructed url's such as: `var add r = 'b'+'la.com';`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. What can I do if is an external js to load the second page? For example if the terget site has a div and a jQuery action on click to load another page? How can I redirect it?

Comment: Most likely, the ajax request will be relative. If you set up your server to catch all requests (with proper rewrite rule) you could direct this ajax request to your PHP code, that will make the request to the original server